# Spring Boot Vaadin Validation does not work - Why?

Tags: spring-boot, vaadin, crud, bean-validation, vaadin14

I'm using Vaadin 14 with Vaadin CRUD AddOns and it seems that my validation does not work for me.

If I open my CRUD view and look at these two fields. They are empty strings e.g null. I'm suppose to recieve an error "must not be null". But here, I get no error at all.

[image]

My entity looks like this.

```
@Entity(name = "Data")
@Data
public class Data {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long id;
    
    @NotNull
    private String OrderNumber;
    @NotNull
    private String SerialNumber;
```

And if I trying to save to my database, it looks like this.

```
Caused by: javax.validation.ConstraintViolationException: Validation failed for classes [se.danielmartensson.entities.LX_Data] during update time for groups [javax.validation.groups.Default, ]
List of constraint violations:[
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=SerialNumber, rootBeanClass=class se.danielmartensson.entities.Data, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
    ConstraintViolationImpl{interpolatedMessage='must not be null', propertyPath=OrderNumber, rootBeanClass=class se.danielmartensson.entities.Data, messageTemplate='{javax.validation.constraints.NotNull.message}'}
]
```

That is weird because my `pom.xml` has `Spring Boot Starter Validation` included. Something Vaadin him self says it should be included: https://vaadin.com/learn/tutorials/introduction-to-java-bean-validation

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.example.application</groupId>
    <artifactId>test-data</artifactId>
    <name>Project base for Spring Boot and Vaadin Flow</name>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <vaadin.version>14.5.2</vaadin.version>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.4</version>
    </parent>

    <repositories>
        <!-- The order of definitions matters. Explicitly defining central here to make sure it has the highest priority. -->

        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <repository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
        <!-- Repository used by many Vaadin add-ons -->
        <repository>
            <id>Vaadin Directory</id>
            <url>https://maven.vaadin.com/vaadin-addons</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <pluginRepositories>
        <!-- Main Maven repository -->
        <pluginRepository>
            <id>central</id>
            <url>https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </pluginRepository>
    </pluginRepositories>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <!-- Replace artifactId with vaadin-core to use only free components -->
            <artifactId>vaadin</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Webjars are only needed when running in Vaadin 13 compatibility mode -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin.webjar</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.insites</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymer</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.polymerelements</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.webjars.bowergithub.webcomponents</groupId>
                    <artifactId>*</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Excluding so that webjars are not included. -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                    <artifactId>vaadin-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.artur</groupId>
            <artifactId>a-vaadin-helper</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- FTP Client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Getter & Setter -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Data base -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        
        <!--  
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency> -->
        
        <!-- CRUD -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.vaadin.crudui</groupId>
            <artifactId>crudui</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.2</version>
        </dependency>
        
        <!-- Charts -->
        <dependency>
           <groupId>com.github.appreciated</groupId>
           <artifactId>apexcharts</artifactId>
           <version>2.0.0.beta11</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
            <artifactId>vaadin-testbench</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- Include JUnit 4 support for TestBench and others -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
            <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <!-- Clean build and startup time for Vaadin apps sometimes may exceed
                     the default Spring Boot's 30sec timeout.  -->
                <configuration>
                    <wait>500</wait>
                    <maxAttempts>240</maxAttempts>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

            <!--
                Take care of synchronizing java dependencies and imports in
                package.json and main.js files.
                It also creates webpack.config.js if not exists yet.
            -->
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>prepare-frontend</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <!-- Production mode is activated using -Pproduction -->
            <id>production</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>com.vaadin</groupId>
                        <artifactId>vaadin-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${vaadin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>build-frontend</goal>
                                </goals>
                                <phase>compile</phase>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <productionMode>true</productionMode>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>it</id>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <id>start-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>pre-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>start</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                            <execution>
                                <id>stop-spring-boot</id>
                                <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>stop</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                    </plugin>

                    <!-- Runs the integration tests (*IT) after the server is started -->
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                <goals>
                                    <goal>integration-test</goal>
                                    <goal>verify</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
                            <enableAssertions>true</enableAssertions>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>

    </profiles>
</project>
```

I'm expecting a behaviour like this.

[image]

Please, see this web application and try to change the CRUD by pressing at the pen above. Try to update with a clean text field.

https://alejandro.app.fi/crud-ui-demo/simple

And his Entity looks like this.

```
/**
 * @author Alejandro Duarte
 */
@Entity
public class User {

    @NotNull
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    private String name;
```

https://github.com/alejandro-du/crudui/blob/master/demo/src/main/java/org/vaadin/crudui/demo/entity/User.java

And yes, I'm using

```
crud.getCrudFormFactory().setUseBeanValidation(true);
```

Here:

```
// Configuration of the grid
GridCrud<Data> crud = new GridCrud<>(Data.class);
crud.getGrid().setColumns("orderNumber", "serialNumber");
crud.getGrid().setColumnReorderingAllowed(true);

// Filter
TextField orderNumberFilter = createFilterField("Order Number", crud);
TextField serialNumberFilter = createFilterField("Serial Number", crud);
crud.getCrudLayout().addFilterComponents(orderNumberFilter, serialNumberFilter);

// Configuration of the user interface
crud.getCrudFormFactory().setUseBeanValidation(true);
crud.getCrudFormFactory().setVisibleProperties("orderNumber", "serialNumber");
crud.getCrudFormFactory().setDisabledProperties("id");
```

Comment: They are indeed not null because i think there is an empty string. Try @NotBlank instead

Comment: @SimonMartinelli it's working now thanks to Erik Lumme's answer. But if I want to delete an entitiy (row in the database) who is blank but not null? The Vaadin Crud AddOn will assume that blank String fields are null

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems that based on your setters and getters, it finds the `orderNumber` and `serialNumber` properties.

However, you name your fields `OrderNumber` and `SerialNumber`, which is not the standard naming convention. Because of this, it does not make the connection between those annotations and properties.

You can do one of two things:

1. Rename your fields to `orderNumber` and `serialNumber`.
2. Move the annotations to the getter methods. It looks like you're using Lombok, so you'd have to define those getters first, or perhaps using `@Getter(onMethod_=@NotNull)` on your field.

Comment: You mean that I should use `@Getter(onMethod_=NotNull) private String serialNumber` field?

Comment: This project works fine with Crud Addon https://github.com/DanielMartensson/OpenSourceLogger/blob/master/src/main/java/se/danielmartensson/entities/Job.java I will try your #1 suggestion.

Comment: It's working now! But one small question. If I want to delete an entitiy that have some null fields. Should I use the getter then so I can insert non-Null values and delete null values?